# Play framework 2.2 "hot fixing" live production server

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, netty

I'm fiddling around with Play Framework 2.2, trying various scenarios and coming from LAMP environment I have this question: is some form of hot fixing possible on live production server? If so, how exactly does it work? If no, then what is the closest thing?

Server OS is Centos 6.4. Equivalent example in LAMP would be re-uploading some file with a hot fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot hot fix a play framework application like you would a php application. Everything in a play framework application is compiled, so if you hot-switch one of your files on the server, the change will not have any affect before it is compiled and the server is restarted.

Instead of hot fixing, consider having a reverse proxy in front of your play application (Apache and Nginx are good alternatives). When you need to update your application, just upload it to a new folder and start it with a new port number. When the new server instance is up and running, switch the reverse proxy to point at the new instance. Then shut the old instance down.

With this approach, you can safely update your server without downtime.

Comment: Actually you can "almost" hotfix if you compile the stage binaries on another machine, move them over, kill play and run the stage script. It will be down for a few seconds, but it's much better than the alternative. Also, use varnish if you want a proxy/loadbalancer. It's much much more efficient :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with Play (or most other web frameworks for that matter).  To allow zero time deploys, you typically have a load balancer, and then do rolling upgrades across your nodes, taking one node at a time out of the cluster to upgrade it.

Comment: ...and of course Play makes this easier given that it is stateless. :-)

Comment: The trick is applying evolutions, if you do database changes that aren't backwards compatible with the old version of your app...Boom